# Yahoo auction placebid api url

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I am working in auction website using yahoo japan auction API. I have a search and product details page API URL. But I don't know how to bid yahoo action using the API.

This [link](http://developer.yahoo.co.jp/webapi/auctions/) does not guide how to bid yahoo auctions using the API. I have spent much more time for searching this flow but of not use.

I am trying this code

```
<form action="http://bid11.auctions.yahoo.co.jp/jp/config/placebid" method="post" onsubmit="disabledSubmit(this)">
   <input type="hidden" name="Partial" value="0">
   <input type="hidden" name="ItemID" value="n121912467">
   <input type="hidden" name="login" value="suresh_3971">
   <input type="hidden" name="cc" value="jp">
   <input type="hidden" name="Quantity" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="Bid" value="15,500">
   <input type="hidden" name="bidType" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="a" value="dj0zaiZpPU9jRE5IdWYyQVFOaCZkPVlXazlaVlp6UmxGTE5XRW1jR285TUEtLSZzPWNvbnN1bWVyc2VjcmV0Jng9M2M-">
   <input type="hidden" name="u" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

how to bid yahoo auctions using the API?

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?